# c++ vector template argument 1 is invalid

Tags: c++, templates, vector, reference

I wrote a `File` class in `File.h`. And I wrote Directory class in `Directory.h` which is include `File&` vector. Two header has same namespace.

Here is the code:

```
#include "File.h" 
#include <vector>

class Directory : public File
{
public:
    ...

private:
    std::vector<(File&)> files; 
};
```

When I try to compile it, it says:

```
In file included from Directory.cpp:1:0:
Directory.h:29:30: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         std::vector<(File&)> files; 
                              ^
Directory.h:29:30: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Comment: You cannot have `std::vector` of reference types. The type must be copyable. Any reason why not to use `std::vector<File>`?

Comment: Then I should use pointers? Thank you.

Comment: And you need them for? Polymorphism?

Comment: Indeed. Because of this, I can't use File vector. But std::vector<File>& files works too I guess

Comment: No, it won't work. the best is to have vector of smart pointers.

Comment: Okay, I'll use pointer. Thank you.

Comment: You missed LogicStuff's point.   Although there is a relationship, a smart pointer is distinct from a pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clear things up for you, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) requires its elements to be [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable), which references aren't.

`std::vector<File&>` is a vector of references to `File`, note that `std::vector<(File&)>` is a syntax error.

You thought `std::vector<File> &` would work, but no. It's a reference to a vector of what? Objects. Polymorphism won't work there. And you'd need an actual `std::vector<File>` instance to refer to.

You need a vector of pointers, which *can* be copy-assigned.

If you go with raw pointers, you'll need not to forget `delete` before you remove any element, or you'll leak memory (if an object was allocated on heap, of course). Smart pointers will do that for you:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<File>> files;
// or
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<File>> files;
```

Reference: [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).